# while Device A is running, I want another circuit to be turned on

Tags: electrical

Example: When the clothes dryer is running I want another lamp to be lit.

One way to understand the idea:

- Device A plugs into the clothes dryer outlet.
- Two devices can plug into Device A:
  .. One device is the clothes dryer
  .. The other device is a lamp.
  .. When the dryer is running (drawing current), the lamp turns on. When the dryer is not drawing current, the lamp is off.

Comment: This is trivial with off-the-shelf equipment such as [this APC surge protector](https://amzn.to/3LMHSpv) with a "Master"/"Slave" setup. But that is for 120V, 15A, not 240V/30A.

Comment: what do you need to illuminate?

Comment: @Jasen I'm presuming he wants a notification light like the "on air" light you might get at a radio station. Light goes off when the dryer goes off so he knows it's done running. Either the buzzer is broken or he's too far away to hear it.

Comment: Is the dryer gas or electric? (240V or 120V)? Note a 240V dryer has current movement *on neutral* with 100% certainty when running, whereas you can't count on either hot. (one hot has no current during fluff cycle or whenever the heating element is not energized, and you can't predict which hot).

Comment: that would be my guess too, but he said "lamp" not "signal" or "indicator"

Answer (score 2):

You need a load-sensing switch. Inside one of those, electrical activity in one circuit causes another circuit to come on (or go off) depending on how it's all hooked up.

You can buy them as ["stand-alone" devices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YK9VBQK) for such things as turning on a dust collector when you start up your table saw, or considering this is a DIY site, here are [plans for building your own](https://ibuildit.ca/projects/automatic-load-sensing-switch/) at John Heisz's website for considerably less than that.

Comment: Buyer beware: The stand-alone device you linked is almost definitely **not** approved for sale/use in the US. It mentions UL listing for the power cord (but not the rest) and talks about handling 30A on a 14AWG cord in a 15A connector. Among other problems. There are, however, plenty of perfectly legitimate devices like [this APC](https://amzn.to/3LMHSpv). But in any case, you need something here that can handle a dryer circuit.

Comment: Yes. Be careful buying stuff like this from Amazon, eBay, WalMart, etc. Good catch on that, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact. I scanned the write-up and saw _"220V"_ and _"UL-listed"_...

Comment: This appears to be an updated version of his switch. I asked the folks at [electronics.se] (in chat, it was a shopping question) about a suitable replacement for a part for his earlier design and they gave a warning that it was very poorly designed - I'd suggest asking there about the design of this one, too. Additionally, this exact design won't work for a 240v dryer and 120v light, though someone with knowledge could modify it. Finally, it puts all the load on one circuit which could be an issue for a large table saw & dust collector setup.

Comment: Thanks, all! I I did not know about the feature being built into some power strips, but that looks like exactly what I want. 

To the question about what the lamp is for, I used "lamp" simply as an example of a simple, light load.